# OnMarkerFound event not getting called - Unity3D ARToolKit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I am trying to get some custom behaviour implemented using ARToolKit SDK on Unity3D.
According to the documentation [here](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=6_Unity:unity_low_level_api), the `ARCamera` uses the `BroadcastMessage` system to call `OnMarkerFound(ARMarker marker)` and `OnMarkerLost(ARMarker marker)` to notify when a marker is found or lost.
However, I cannot get these functions to fire at all. I have gone through the entire source code, added debug watches, the works... But these two events are not firing.
My script looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CustomTrack : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMarkerFound(ARMarker marker){
        Debug.Log("MARKER FOUND! WHEEEE!");
    }

    void OnMarkerLost(ARMarker marker){
        Debug.Log("MARKER LOST! WHEEEE!");
    }

    void OnMarkerTracked(ARMarker marker){
         Debug.Log("MARKER TRACKED! WHEEEE!");
    }
}
```

I have seen several other people on forums, etc. facing similar problems so it would be nice to finally have a solution to this issue.

---

### EDIT - Answer

Just to explain what I did to get this working, going by what @bleater said, I added the `GameObject` to the `ARTrackedObject` and then added my `CustomScript` to the `GameObject`. One mistake I was making was to attach the `CustomScript` to the `ARMarkerScene`. So, that worked. I hope this is useful to others as well.

Comment: I admit the doc is a bit confusing. It says the object holding the script should be a child of the AROrigin GameObject. Do you have it so? You should also set some tags. That docs seems pretty old as it makes use of some deprecated methods. Could be outdated.

Comment: @fafase I've done those things correctly. My program works as normally expected, so that's fine. I just want to add some custom functionality.

Comment: The question is about the events not being called but now you say you got it but want some customisation. Could you rephrase the problem? I am getting lost a bit.

Comment: @fafase What I mean is unless those events get called, I am unable to do any custom actions when a marker gets detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit out of date, as since ARToolKit for Unity v5.2 those events are generated by the ARTrackedObject component. The object that is to receive the events must be connected to the "Event receiver" on the ARTrackedObject, this is exposed in the Editor:

[image: Unity Editor panel for ARTrackedObject]

Since BroadcastMessage is used, the event receiver and any children will all receive the message, so if you need more than one GameObject to be called, put them into a group and make the parent object the event receiver.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Been waiting for an answer for so long. I'll try what you said. But what I want to know is how does this work exactly? Once I attach an object to the receiver, the functions will get called for that object?

Comment: Where would my function script go in this case? Should I attach it to the GameObject in question?

Comment: Attach it to whatever you want to receive the events, even an empty GameObject.

Comment: end of April 2017 and the documentation is still out of date. p.s. thanks for posting this